# In java, list all files recursively. but skip one sub-directory

Tags: java

I am listing all the files names in a given directory( recursively). That includes showing the file names in sub-directories also. How I can restrict it to not to show the files/dir under one specific sub-directory (skip one specific directory)

```
    File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
    // Recursively search for all the resource files.
    Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(file, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
    for (Iterator iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
    {
        File fileIter = (File) iterator.next();
        System.out.println("File = " + fileIter.getPath());

    }
```

Comment: Yeah , adding a simple if logic will work here !!

Comment: You can use a FileFilter as well

Comment: I wondered if there would be better inbuilt option like "filefilter" than using "if"

Comment: I am puzzled both by your decision to use raw types (like Collection instead of `Collection<File>`) and your decision to use a third party library to do something Java SE [already does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-).

Comment: @VGR, I am surprised, except you, no one ever pointed me to this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java SE has its own method for doing this:  [Files.walkFileTree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-).  You pass it a FileVisitor (usually a subclass of SimpleFileVisitor), each of whose methods can return a [FileVisitResult](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitResult.html).  To skip a directory, simply return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE:

```
Files.walkFileTree(file.toPath(),
    new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
                                                 BasicFileAttributes attr)
        throws IOException {
            if (dir.endsWith("forbiddenDir")) {
                return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                                         BasicFileAttributes attr)
        throws IOException {
            System.out.println("File = " + file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
```

The [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) class is the modern replacement for the obsolete File class.  You should avoid using File, since many of its methods do not report errors properly.  If you absolutely need a File object, Path has a toFile() method.  Conversely, File has a toPath() method.